# how to get change current date color?

Tags: android

below is my code which get current week dates and print in buttons how i change color of current date???  just only need to change the color of today date? how i will do that????
mDay  is current date. change the color of today date to blue how is possible??

```
    public class HoyahCalendar extends Activity {
public static int mYear;
public static int currentIndex = -1;
public static int mMonth;
public static int mDay;
public static String[][] a = new String[6][7];

         Calendar mCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    mYear = mCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    mMonth = mCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1;
    mDay = mCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);




               public void showOnScreen() {

    if (mMonth ==1) 
    {
        Monthname="January";
        }
    else 
        if (mMonth ==2) { 
            Monthname="February";
            }

        else
    if (mMonth ==3) { Monthname="March";}
    else 
        if (mMonth ==4) { Monthname="April";    }

        else
    if (mMonth ==5) { Monthname="May";}
    else 
        if (mMonth ==6) { Monthname="June"; }
        else
    if (mMonth ==7) { Monthname="July";}
    else 
        if (mMonth ==8) { Monthname="August";   }
        else
    if (mMonth ==9) { Monthname="September";}
    else 
        if (mMonth ==10)    { Monthname="October";  }
    if (mMonth ==11)    { Monthname="November";}
    else 
        if (mMonth ==12)    { Monthname="December"; }


    date_today.setText(  Monthname + "  " +mYear);
    e00.setText("" + a[0][0]);
    e01.setText("" + a[0][1]);
    e02.setText("" + a[0][2]);
    e03.setText("" + a[0][3]);
    e04.setText("" + a[0][4]);
    e05.setText("" + a[0][5]);
    e06.setText("" + a[0][6]);

}


  public class ShowCalendar {
 int mYear;
  int mMonth;
int mDay;
public ShowCalendar(int mYear, int mMonth){
    this.mYear = mYear;
    this.mMonth = mMonth;

    calculateMonthFirstday();
}


public int getmDay() {
    return mDay;
}


public void setmDay(int mDay) {
    this.mDay = mDay;
}


public ShowCalendar(int mYear, int mMonth, int mDay, String time){
    this.mYear = mYear;
    this.mMonth = mMonth;
    if (time == "next"){
        HoyahCalendar.currentIndex++;
        if (HoyahCalendar.currentIndex == 5){
            HoyahCalendar.currentIndex--;
        }
        this.mDay = mDay + 7;
    } else if (time == "last"){
        HoyahCalendar.currentIndex--;
        if (HoyahCalendar.currentIndex == -1){
            HoyahCalendar.currentIndex++;
        }
        this.mDay = mDay - 7;
    }
    calculateMonthFirstday();
}

public void calculateMonthFirstday(){
    int month, first_day=0;
    if((mYear%4==0 && mYear%100!=0)||(mYear%400==0))
        month=1;
    else
        month=0;

    int y, y12, c, c12, m, d;
    y = mYear%100;
    y12 = (mYear-1)%100; //only for January and February
    c = mYear/100;
    c12 = (mYear-1)/100;
    m = mMonth;
    d = 1;

    switch(mMonth){
    case 1: {first_day = y12 + y12/4 +c12/4 - 2*c12 + 26*(13 + 1)/10 + d - 1;break;}
    case 2: {first_day = y12 + y12/4 +c12/4 - 2*c12 + 26*(14 + 1)/10 + d - 1;break;}
    case 4: {first_day = y + y/4 +c/4 - 2*c + 26*(m + 1)/10 + d - 1;break;}
    case 5: {first_day = y + y/4 +c/4 - 2*c + 26*(m + 1)/10 + d - 1;break;}
    case 6: {first_day = y + y/4 +c/4 - 2*c + 26*(m + 1)/10 + d - 1;break;}
    case 7: {first_day = y + y/4 +c/4 - 2*c + 26*(m + 1)/10 + d - 1;break;}
    case 8: {first_day = y + y/4 +c/4 - 2*c + 26*(m + 1)/10 + d - 1;break;}
    case 9: {first_day = y + y/4 +c/4 - 2*c + 26*(m + 1)/10 + d - 1;break;}
    case 10: {first_day = y + y/4 +c/4 - 2*c + 26*(m + 1)/10 + d - 1;break;}
    case 11: {first_day = y + y/4 +c/4 - 2*c + 26*(m + 1)/10 + d - 1;break;}
    case 12: {first_day = y + y/4 +c/4 - 2*c + 26*(m + 1)/10 + d - 1;break;}
    }
    if(first_day<0)
        first_day = 7 - (Math.abs(first_day))%7;//first_day每月第一天星期几
    else
        first_day = first_day%7;

    switch(mMonth){
        case 1: {CalculateCalendar(1,first_day,31);break;}
        case 2: {CalculateCalendar(2,first_day,28+month);break;}
        case 3: {CalculateCalendar(3,first_day,31);break;}
        case 4: {CalculateCalendar(4,first_day,30);break;}
        case 5: {CalculateCalendar(5,first_day,31);break;}
        case 6: {CalculateCalendar(6,first_day,30);break;}
        case 7: {CalculateCalendar(7,first_day,31);break;}
        case 8: {CalculateCalendar(8,first_day,31);break;}
        case 9: {CalculateCalendar(9,first_day,30);break;}
        case 10:{CalculateCalendar(10,first_day,31);break;}
        case 11:{CalculateCalendar(11,first_day,30);break;}
        case 12:{CalculateCalendar(12,first_day,31);break;}
    }
}

public void CalculateCalendar(int month_no, int week_no, int month_days){

    int i, s, targetRow = 0;
    int currentDay;
    if (this.mDay == 0){
        currentDay= HoyahCalendar.mDay;     
    }else {
        currentDay = this.mDay;
    }
    //String[][] a = new String[6][7];
    for (i=0;i<week_no;i++)
        HoyahCalendar.a[i/7][i%7] = "";

    for(i=week_no; i<week_no + month_days; i++){
        s = i - week_no + 1;
        HoyahCalendar.a[i/7][i%7] = String.valueOf(s);
        if (s == currentDay && HoyahCalendar.currentIndex == -1){
            HoyahCalendar.currentIndex = i/7;
        }
    } 
    for (i=0; i<7;i++){
        if (HoyahCalendar.a[HoyahCalendar.currentIndex][i] == null){
            HoyahCalendar.a[0][i] = "";
        }else{
            HoyahCalendar.a[0][i] = HoyahCalendar.a[HoyahCalendar.currentIndex][i];
        }

    }
    for(i=week_no+month_days; i<42; i++)


        HoyahCalendar.a[i/7][i%7] = "";
}
```

}

Comment: help me please i just need to chang the color of today date  how i will do that???

Comment: how to compare  e00.setText("" + a[0][0]); value with (mDay)????